# Custom textwatcher, lag in swiftkey but not in stock keyboard

Tags: android, formatting

I needed a textwatcher that adds thousands separators so I've found this:

```
package utils;

import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Locale;

/**
 * Created by Robby on 4/07/2014.
 */
public class NumberTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static final String TAG = "NumberTextWatcher";
    private final TextView currencyIndicator;
    private DecimalFormat df;
    private DecimalFormat dfnd;
    private boolean hasFractionalPart;
    private EditText et;


    public NumberTextWatcher(TextView currencyIndicator, EditText et) {
        DecimalFormatSymbols otherSymbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.GERMANY);
        otherSymbols.setDecimalSeparator(',');
        otherSymbols.setGroupingSeparator('.');

        df = new DecimalFormat("#,###.##", otherSymbols);
        df.setDecimalSeparatorAlwaysShown(true);
        dfnd = new DecimalFormat("#,###", otherSymbols);
        this.et = et;
        hasFractionalPart = false;
        this.currencyIndicator = currencyIndicator;
    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        et.removeTextChangedListener(this);

        if (s != null && s.length() > 0) {
            currencyIndicator.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            currencyIndicator.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        try {
            int inilen, endlen;
            inilen = et.getText().length();
            String v = s.toString().replace(String.valueOf(df.getDecimalFormatSymbols().getGroupingSeparator()), "");
            Number n = df.parse(v);
            int cp = et.getSelectionStart();
            if (hasFractionalPart) {
                et.setText(df.format(n));
            } else {
                et.setText(dfnd.format(n));
            }
            endlen = et.getText().length();
            int sel = (cp + (endlen - inilen));
            if (sel > 0 && sel <= et.getText().length()) {
                et.setSelection(sel);
            } else {
                // place cursor at the end?
                et.setSelection(et.getText().length() - 1);
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            // do nothing?
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // do nothing?
        }

        et.addTextChangedListener(this);
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        if (s.toString().contains(String.valueOf(df.getDecimalFormatSymbols().getDecimalSeparator()))) {
            hasFractionalPart = true;
        } else {
            hasFractionalPart = false;
        }
    }
}
```

So when I type 100000 it sets the edittext to 100.000 etc...
When I comment out the afterTextChanged block it works very smooth so it must be something in there that causes lag in the swiftkey app.

Is there are more efficient way to do this? Or is this just a bug in swiftkey I shouldn't pay attention to ?

On the stock keyboard I have no lag whatsoever.